# Can I run my desktop on a bare-metal VM layer to swap between operating systems?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, virtualization, xen

I'm running CentOS as my primary desktop, but I need to be able to use Windows and Ubuntu from time to time to test things on those. As I don't have any extra hardware immediately available, I could set up VMs under CentOS for the other two, but wondered whether I could actually just run all of them as guests on a bare-metal virtualisation system like VMWare ESXi or XenServer.

Is there any point in this (except as a learning exercise), and how could I achieve it?

Comment: You can run Ubuntu or Debian using debootstrap, it aways you to install a debian based OS (using apt/deb) on a Linux based system (maybe even bsd kernel), it will run along side using chroot. It is faster than true virtualization, but the kernel is not virtualized. (I thing there is an rpm based bootstrap as well.)

Answer (score 1):

Well, the problem with ESXi is that, while you could run all three on the one platform, you'd only be able to interact with it from another system.  ESXi has no capability to display the guest O/S on it's monitor.

You might look at the free Hyper-V server, which could then run all three?  Or if the Windows machine is Windows 8.1, look at adding the Hyper-V role to that, use Windows 8.1 natively, and run CentOS and Ubuntu from there.